# CefDOMDocument (Chrome Embedding Framework)

Tags: c++, google-chrome, winapi, webkit, chromium-embedded

I using CEF in my application, for rendering web pages. I wand get items coordinates in page (texts,tables, pictures). I fount class CefDOMDocument, but it is abstract class. How get coordinates items (x,y)? Thank. (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: The DOM document provides access to the hierarchical structure of an HTML document. It is unrelated to rendering, and cannot know the location, where any given object will appear.

Comment: CEF renders the page, so somewhere stored location data items.

Comment: I'm sure that CEF can render HTML. I doubt, that it maintains a mapping between HTML entities and coordinates of the rendered output. If it did, I'm convinced, [Atom](https://atom.io/) wouldn't be such a useless toy.